# Por vezes jquery nao funciona

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Tenho um botão numa página que chama um API. O botão permite seguir um utilizador ou deixar de seguir.

Ao clicar no botão é alterada uma label que fica próxima ao botão e o símbolo que esta no botão.

O problema é que ás vezes tudo funciona bem e outras não. Fiz debug e percebi que quando falha é porque o valor vai null para o API. O mais estranho é que ao chegar á página tudo pode funcionar bem as primeiras vez, depois falha, e depois, mesmo sem recarregar a página, volta tudo a funcionar bem.

Aqui fica o código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

           var lblseguir = $(".lbl-seguir");
           var iconSeguir = $('#icon-seguir');

           $(".js-toggle-seguir").click(function (e) {
               var button = $(e.target);

               if (lblseguir.hasClass("label-info"))
               {
                   $.post("/api/seguir", { seguidoId: button.attr("data-user-id") })
                   .done(function () {
                       lblseguir
                           .text("Seguindo")
                           .removeClass("label-info")
                           .addClass("label-success");
                       iconSeguir
                           .removeClass("fa-user-plus")
                           .addClass("fa-user");
                   })
                   .fail(function () {
                       alert("Algo deu errado!")
                   });
               }
               else 
               {
                   $.ajax({
                       url: "/api/seguir/" + button.attr("data-user-id"),
                       method: "DELETE"
                   })
                      .done(function () {
                          lblseguir
                            .text("Seguir")
                            .removeClass("label-seccess")
                            .addClass("label-info");
                          iconSeguir
                           .removeClass("fa-user")
                           .addClass("fa-user-plus");
                      })
                      .fail(function () {
                          alert("Algo deu errado!")
                      })
               }
           });
       }
    );
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o HTML? esse `.js-toggle-seguir` é o botão? acho que o `e.target` ás vezes não é o botão como esperado. Coloca o HTML para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Uuhum. O HTML seria ótimo.

Comment: Abra o console do navegador e então de F5 e comece as ações desde o começo até ocorrer a falha que você citou, então observe se ocorreu algum erro no console, geralmente coisas falham em outros scripts o que causa um efeito "dominó".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se `$(".js-toggle-seguir")` é o próprio botão então dentro dessa função o `this` é o botão clicado. E podes usar:

```
$(".js-toggle-seguir").click(function (e) {
       var button = $(this);
```

ou diretamente tirando o ID:

```
$(".js-toggle-seguir").click(function (e) {
       var userId = this.getAttribute('data-user-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Já resolvi o problema.

Era mesmo na parte do `e.target`.

Fiz o seguinte:

```
var button = $(".js-toggle-favoritos");

button.click(function () {
//buttom.attr já funciona aqui dentro
}
```